# Magento web service login Errors communication exception unrecogized message version

Tags: .net, wcf, magento

i'm writing .Net connector to Magento web services. i created users and admin roles at magento backend.then I added service reference to magento web service url. when i execute magento service login in ,it returns me serviceModel.communicationException : unrecogized message version.

```
   private static Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerPortTypeClient InitializeService(string magentoEndpoint)
        {
            var endPoint = new EndpointAddress(magentoEndpoint);
            var binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None)
                              {
                                  Name = "Mage_Api_Model_Server_V2_HandlerBinding",
                                  CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0),
                                  HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard,
                                  MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text,
                                  MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536000,
                                  MaxBufferSize = 65536000
                              };
}
```

then i call magentoservice
      var magentoService = InitializeService(magentoEndpoint);

```
            //login
 var sessionId = magentoService.login(magentoUsername, magentoKey);
```

Comment: I can't even get started calling the Magento API via .NET. If you make progress, could you take a look at this question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12088459/how-to-call-the-magento-api-from-vb-net

Answer (score 0):

it turned out to be some SSL issues

Comment: It's a shame you didn't go into more details as to how you solved this, as I've run into the exact same issue, over four years later :(